# UiTextView move to next character error with emoji

Tags: ios, uitextview, emoji, nsrange

In a UiTextView i have a function to jump to the next character after the caret:

```
textView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(textView.selectedRange.location+1,0);
```

When i have emoticons it doesn't work, i have to it twice.

I was wondering if i can check if the next character after the caret if a special character so i move 2 instead of 1 in caret location.

And when i try to get the NSString of thaT range it doesn't give anything or error

```
 NSRange myRange = NSMakeRange(textView.selectedRange.location,1);
 [textView.text substringWithRange:myRange]
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `NSString rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex:` method. For most characters this will return a range with a length of 1. But for characters with a Unicode value of U+10000 or more, this will give a range with a length of 2.

This will move the caret to the next character:

```
NSRange nextRange = [textView.text rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex:textView.selectedRange.location];
textView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(nextRange.location + nextRange.length, 0);
```

Comment: Hey, I had my answer almost finished :-) - I only think that the `+ 1` in the first line is wrong.